# How to inject Location in function in NgModule definition file?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, location

I have next code

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
     ..

    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
            deps: [HttpClient]
        }
        }),
 ...

    ],
```

This is createTranslateLoader implementation

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    let fullLocationPath = location.origin + location.pathname;
     // I want to use angular location here.
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, fullLocationPath  + 'assets/languages/', '.json');
}
```

How can I do this? How can i use angular location in createTranslateLoader function?
https://angular.io/api/common/Location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#description) you have to provide a location yourself if you want to use it and also specify the `LocationStrategy`:

```
import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ...
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
            deps: [HttpClient]
        }
        }),
        ...

    ],

    providers: [Location, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}],
```

You can pass any of the 3 location strategies:

- HashLocationStrategy
- PathLocationStrategy
- MockLocationStrategy